# Javafx - Combine the elements of two ArrayLists for Dates and Assignments

Tags: arrays, javafx, datepicker

I have a javafx calendar application that displays dates from an ArrayList in a Date Picker Skin. The appointments and their dates are in a SQL database.

I have retried the dates and displayed them - with a little help - in a Date Picker Skin using an ArrayList.

Now I want the appointment names to be displayed on their respective dates in the Date Picker Skin as tooltips. To the this end I have copied the strings into a separate list.

```
 ArrayList dates (2017-05-05 , 2017-05-15 , 2017-05-25);
 ArrayList tooltips ( Peter , Paul , Mary);
```

My problem is that I cannot get the two lists to match the items, so that each date field represents only the matching tooltip. Instead, each field show all the tooltips. I have tried for-loops and pairs, but all without success. Noteworthy to say that I am a Java beginner with a couple of months of experience.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  ObservableList<LocalDate> dates = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

  while (rs.next()) {

      String  dateFromDatabase = rs.getString("DATE");
      DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
      LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateFromDatabase , formatter);
      dates.add(localDate);

  }

  ObservableList<String> tooltipList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      tooltipList.add("Peter");
      tooltipList.add("Paul"); 
      tooltipList.add("Mary"); 


  Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {

         public DateCell call (final DatePicker datePicker ) {

             return new DateCell() {

                 @Override
                 public void updateItem (LocalDate item , boolean empty) {
                     super.updateItem(item, empty);

                     if (item != null && dates.contains(item)) {

                         this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue; -fx-text-fill: black ;");
                         this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gold");

                    for(int i =0; i< dates.size(); i++) {
                        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip(tooltipList.toString());
                        this.setTooltip(tooltip);


                     } 

                  };

             };

        };

    };
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if my answer truly solves your problem. Meaning you are probably going to run into a new problem. I think your item needs to be an object that holds the LocalDate and the ToolTip info. Your item type is LocalDate. If you had code to actually run this part, I could probably give a better opinion.

Comment: With your current structure, I think you should use HashMap for tooltips ArrayList. The key should be the date String and the tooltip data String should be retrieved by the key.

Comment: Probably you should take some time to read up on how cell factories work. E.g. read the [`Cell` API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html). I have no idea what you think the `for` loop in there is going to do, but a moment's thought will tell you that it just repeatedly sets the tooltip for the cell to the same thing.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson, many thanks for your effort and the suggestion. Lists do match items, but the tooltips still display all for all nodes. I will check out the hashmaps ..,.

Comment: @James_D, thanks for your patience and the time to respond to my question. The for-loop I added was just to show my  line of effort. I am aware of the flaws. The link you added is very informative and I will go through the text with dedication.

Comment: Actually, you need to take James_D advice and learn more about the Cell and Cell Factory. Your `LocalDate item` should be `CustomObject item`. Your `CustomObject` should at least have a LocalDate and a String containing the ToopTip info associated with that LocalDate.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Well, you probably can't use any class other than `LocalDate` in a `DatePickerSkin`, but it's not really clear he should be using a `DatePickerSkin` at all (it will be public API in Java 9, but not in Java 8).

Comment: I went to try it and I think you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This app is probably very similar to what you are looking for, but I suggest you listen to Jame_D's warning and try to find a different approach to implement your calendar. I haven't checked, but I would start with ControlFx or implement your own.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javafxapplication46;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.util.*;

public class JavaFXApplication46 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
        map.put("2017-05-28", "Peter");
        map.put("2017-05-30", "Paul");
        map.put("2017-05-31", "Mary");
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        DatePicker endDatePicker = new DatePicker();

        final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
            @Override
            public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker)
            {
                return new DateCell() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty)
                    {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                            if (item.toString().equals(entry.getKey())) {
                                setTooltip(new Tooltip(map.get(item.toString())));
                            }
                            //System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
                            //
                        }

                    }
                };
            }
        };
        endDatePicker.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);
        endDatePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        vbox.getChildren().add(new Label("End Date:"));
        vbox.getChildren().add(endDatePicker);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks for the snippet, Sedrick , works perfectly using ArrayList entries for the keys and the strings ...

Comment: Looking back on this, the `for-loop` does not make sense here. It seems like ` setTooltip(new Tooltip(map.get(item.toString())));` should be all that is needed.